# Image won't appear in div despite setting the height pixels

Tags: html, css

I just started out a day ago and i've been following this tutorial to make a login box. But I can't seem to make the background image appear inside the div even though i have set the height. The directory is 100% correct, I've checked it a thousand times.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</link>
</head>
<body>
<div class="loginbox">
<div class="inner-loginbox">
    <div class="loginbox-front"></div>
    <div class="loginbox-back"></div>
</div>
</div>
<?PHP include('footer.php');?>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.loginbox {
width: 400px;
height: 450px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255);
margin: 10px auto;
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 0 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
text-align: center;
}

.inner-loginbox {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.loginbox-front .loginbox-back {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,100,0.8), rgba(0,0,100,0.8)),url(../images/loginbox.gif);
padding: 55px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: You call wrong css for `.loginbox-back` use `.loginbox .loginbox-back {}`

Comment: wow, it worked. But i still don't understand. The guy in the tutorial used `.loginbox-front .loginbox-back {}` and it still worked. And when I included .loginbox-front the img bg vanishes completely. Would love to know the explanation! Cheers @MinalChauhan

Comment: `.loginbox-front .loginbox-back ` only work if `.loginbox-back` is child of `.loginbox-front` and in your demo both are siblings

Comment: I see. I can do `.loginbox-front, .loginbox-back` . I just have to put a comma in between. Thanks @MinalChauhan .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a comma in between `.loginbox-front, .loginbox-back` will do the trick because `.loginbox-front` and `.loginbox-back` is siblings.

Answer (score 0):

your image directory may be correct. Do you check is your php file including directory  correct? Are you sure do you have your html file and your included php files in same folder.

Comment: yeah it's all in the same folder.